# A hand is rotating a circular or spherical object such that there is no slipping between hand and object. Does translational motion exist?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

I myself thought of a situation where a ring/disc/sphere or any circular/round object is on a frictionless surface and a person is rotating it with his hand. The case is such that the hand always touches the same point and there is pure rolling (no slipping) between hand and that point. Is there any translational motion in the object?

I tried of many ways to think about this problem but couldn't think of any approach which would give me the answer.